# Oracle Query gives different results

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have the following query in a proprietary search engine:

```
ibernate:  SELECT COUNT(1)    FROM CAT_PRODUCTOSHTML PH     WHERE PH.IDPORTAL = ?  AND 0 < CONTAINS(PH.HTMLBUSQUEDAS, '%cuñete%')
```

However it gives different results if i execute it from PL/SQL Developer:

```
5
```

or via Hibernate native query

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
...
return query.getResultList();

Result: 0
```

I have some suspects on the oracle session but i'm not sure about it, also i have tried without success:

```
'%cuñete%'
'%cu\ñete%'
```

Comment: Have you tried `getSingleResult`?

Comment: This sounds like a character encoding issue to me. What is your characterset? select * from v$NLS_PARAMETERS

Comment: Have you tried to avoid the n-tilde in your match expression, e.g. Using `%cu_ete%`?